# Nservicebus Same Message Different Queues - Load Balancing

Tags: load-balancing, nservicebus

Let me explain what I am trying to achieve here:

Create 5 copies of same service each listening to a queue specific to them. The message they listen to would be same

```
SVC1 listening to Q1
SVC2 listening to Q2
SVC3 listening to Q3
SVC4 listening to Q4
SVC5 listening to Q5
```

Say they all listen to a message called `TestMessage`.

Do a Round Robin load balancing between these 5 services and drop the message to the applicable queue based on the output of my round robin logic

My question how do I configure to drop TestMessage to one queue at a point of time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the built-in [Distributor](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/859556-load-balancing-with-the-distributor).  This will perform the load balancing for you and take care of all the work distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The Distributor is what you need to use. It has its own input queue and a queue for available workers. Everytime a worker is available, it will place a message in the distributors input queue and the distributor will send it the next message in its input queue.

Below is a sample application by Mikael Koskinen that demonstrates how to use this:
http://mikaelkoskinen.net/nservicebus-distributor-sample-application/